# Retrieving baseVal or animVal using Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

In the same way animVal can be used to retrieve the animated transform values, (ex. `path.transform.animVal[0].angle`) can baseVal and animVal also be used to retrieve animated stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset values ? (javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset are CSS properties and not attributes.

Only attributes have baseVal and animVal. With CSS properties only the animated value is retrievable.